# Is List<T>.ConvertAll<TOutput> guaranteed to return its output in the same order as its input?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is 'yes', but just in case:

If you're using [ConvertAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) to convert elements of an input list to an output list, is the output list guaranteed to be in the same order as the input list?

Comment: I wouldn't assume it, there's nothing that requires it in the documentation.

Comment: Did you test to find out what it does?

Comment: If the order if your elements is important, I think it's better to be able to determine the desired order by inspecting the elements themselves, i.e. ensure that the types expose properties which can be used to sort a list of them accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit guarantee in the documentation that this is the case.  The documentation only specifies that elements will be individually passed to the delegate and then put into the new `List<T>`.  It doesn't ever specify order.

However the behavior today is that elements are returned in order and there is no conceivable reason this would ever change.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I have one intermittent bug that would be explained if ConvertAll() wasn't always returning results in a predictable order, but I knew it couldn't be that simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the documentation doesn't mention the order of the resulting collection, so it's not guaranteed.

Practically, yeah, I *think* you can rely on the fact that the order of the output will be the same as the order of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it isn't guaranteed. The documentation does not require that it happens that way. That being said most reasonable implementations would work that way.